# A word for evidence used to tell if someone has been in your room

Tags: single-word-requests, legalese, science

I know there's an actual word for this. I used to know the word, but I've lost it.

The word describes a category of methods that someone uses to detect if someone has been in a room, or opened a door, or drawer, or folder, etc...

Examples:
1) Putting a strip of paper in a door jam, so it falls if someone opens the door.
2) Putting powder on the floor that will be removed or scattered.
3) Putting a ball behind a door in a specific location, so if the door is opened, it can't be placed back where it was with certainty.
4) Putting tape across a drawer that will be broken if the drawer is opened.

I imagine this word would be associated with forensic science, security, or criminal / legal work.

Comment: Can you remember where you heard it? A James Bond film? A police documentary?

Comment: Might the single word be an acronym like PIDS (Perimeter Intrusion Detection System)?

Comment: The Goldilocks Test.

Comment: I read about it in a non-fiction book about spies (that I can't remember).  It was a weird word and seemed really specific to the one purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the British Army, that's just called a 'tell'.

Comment: Of course, "tell" is also used in, eg, poker, to refer to a player's tic or other action which provides a clue to the cards he holds.

Comment: I think that maybe this was the word, I just don't remember at this point.  In any case, it's specific enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of:

[***telltale***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/telltale):

> 2. Something that indicates or reveals information; a sign.<sup>1</sup>

Also from [Wordnik](https://wordnik.com/words/telltale)

> n. A machine or contrivance for indicating or recording something, particularly for keeping a check upon employees (factory hands, watchmen, drivers, etc.) by revealing to their employers what they have done or omitted.<sup>2</sup>
>
> n. Something that serves to reveal something else<sup>3</sup>

In this way, the paper you place in the door is a *contrivance for indicating or recording* / *revealing* whether a person has entered the room.

And as @SamBurns correctly states, this is often shortened to simply a *tell*.

---

<sup>1 <sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>
<sup>2 <sub>Wiktionary, Creative Commons Attribution/Share-Alike License</sub></sup>
<sup>3 <sub>The GNU version of the Collaborative International Dictionary of English</sub></sup>

Answer (score 1):

The "category of methods" you list in your question ("has been in a room" or, opened a door, drawer or folder) all fall under the umbrella term "intrusion". So maybe the term you're looking for is:

> Intrusion Detection System

It's a term commonly used in computer networking to describe security applications that patrol for malicious activity ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system)).

Maybe the term has other applications? *Home Intrusion Detection System*, perhaps?

---

Also, your example scenarios, when they work as planned, may result in a:

**giveaway**

> a thing that makes an inadvertent revelation ~ [Google definition](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=giveaway%20definition)

**dead giveaway**

> an unmistakable and definitive clue ~ [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dead+giveaway)
>
> something that reveals a fact or an intention completely ~ [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+giveaway)